# How to find all objects of type Item with thier parent type Family

Tags: sql-server

Here is my Objects table -

[image]

I am trying to write a query that can fetch all objects of type C with their parent of type A. So the query should return like

[image]

I am trying to do it using recursion but not getting the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: can you please share your current query ?

Comment: your object table doesn't have any objects of C with parentObjectId 1

Comment: It's a hierachy @SEarle1986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you what you are after, but if the logic is right for your requirements is a different question:

```
DECLARE @ObjectID int = 3;
DECLARE @EndType char(1) = 'A';

WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'A',NULL),
                (2,'B',1),
                (3,'C',2))V(ObjectID, ObjectType, ParentID)),
rCTE AS(
    SELECT V.ObjectID,
           V.ObjectType,
           V.ParentID,
           V.ObjectID AS StartID, 
           V.ObjectType AS StartType 
    FROM VTE V
    WHERE v.ObjectID = @ObjectID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT V.ObjectID,
           V.ObjectType,
           V.ParentID,
           r.StartID,
           r.StartType
    FROM rCTE r
         JOIN VTE V ON V.ObjectID = r.ParentID)
SELECT r.StartID AS ObjectID,
       r.StartType AS ObjectType,
       r.ObjectID AS ParentObjectID,
       r.ObjectType AS PArentObjectType
FROM rCTe r
WHERE r.ObjectType = @EndType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE (ObjectId INT,ObjectType VARCHAR(2),ParentObjectId INT)
INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT 1,'A',NUll UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'B',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'C',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'D',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'E',4 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'B',3
```

Sql server Script

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT ObjectId,
       ObjectType,
       ParentObjectId,
       CAST('\'+ CAST(ObjectId AS VARCHAR(MAX))AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [ObjectIdHierarchy] ,
       CAST('\'+ ObjectType AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Hierarchy] 
FROM @Temp
WHERE ParentObjectId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t.ObjectId,
       t.ObjectType,
       t.ParentObjectId,
       [ObjectIdHierarchy]+'\'+ CAST(t.ObjectId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [ObjectIdHierarchy],
       [Hierarchy]+'\'+ t.ObjectType  AS [Hierarchy]

FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN @Temp t
ON t.ParentObjectId = c.ObjectId
)
SELECT ObjectId,
       ObjectType, 
   LEFT(RIGHT([ObjectIdHierarchy],LEN([ObjectIdHierarchy])-1),1) AS ParentObjectId,
   LEFT(RIGHT([Hierarchy],LEN([Hierarchy])-1),1) AS ParentChildHierarchy 
FROM CTE
WHERE ObjectId =1
```

Result

```
ObjectId    ObjectType  ParentObjectId  ParentChildHierarchy
------------------------------------------------------------
1               A           1                   A
```